# Como indicar en Java que una dia de la semana viene obligatoriamente despues de otra?

Tags: java

[image]

**He extraido los dias de la semana que viene en letras(L,M,C,J,V,S,D) de cada entrada y los he metido en un array de char**

Tengo que validar los dias de la semana indicando que si no siguen este criterio de ordenacion (L,M,C,J,V,S,D) se eliminen, es decir:

> (L,M,C) es correcto porque despues de lunes viene martes y despues
>   miercoles
>
> (L,M,J) es correcto tambien aunque se salte x dias(sigue el orden de la semana)
>
> (L,J,M) es inorrecto porque despues del jueves no puede ir martes

```
public void validarDiasSemana() {

        while(it.hasNext()) {

            reunion = (Reunion) it.next();

            char[] diasSemanaInput = reunion.getDiasSemana();

        }
   }
```

En la variable **diasSemanaInput** tengo guardado todos los dias de la semana de cada entrada. Y no se como validarlo

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta es solo valida si siempre tienen que empezar por lunes.

Debemos de tener un Char[] que contiene los dias de la semana en el orden. Esta variable la llamaremos `semana`

```
boolean error=false;
for(int i=0;i<diasSemanaInput.length;i++)
{
    if(!diasSemanaInput[i].equals(semana[i]))
    {
       error = true;
       break;
    }
}
if(error)
{
    //codigo a ejecutar en caso de error
}
```

Recorremos la lista char `reunion` y vamos comparando cada elemento de la lista con `diasSemanaInput`

Si en algun momento no coinciden, marcamos error a true y salimos del bucle

Comment: reunion contiene cada entrada entera, mientras que diasSemanaInput contiene solo los dias de la semana de cada entrada.

Comment: He modificado el código al comentario. Sera necesario tener la lista de los días de la semana en el orden deseado.

Answer (score 0):

```
static String semanaOrdenada = "LMCJVSDLMCJVS";


public boolean secuenciaValida(char[] secuencia) {
   return (secuencia != null
             && secuencia.length > 0
             && secuencia.length <= 7
             && semanaOrdenada.contains(new String(secuencia));
}
```

Ese método sería si pudiera iniciar con cualquier día de la semana. Si se tuviera que
iniciar con lunes agregaría la condición:

```
&& secuencia[0] = 'L'
```

Answer (score 0):

Si los arreglos de días tienen huecos se me ocurre que cada día de la semana se le asigne una ponderación, para L=1, M=2 .... D=7, y los arreglos de chars convertirlos a arreglos de int, para poder hacer comparaciones del primero si es menor que el dia que le sigue, sino el arreglo esta desordenado  y el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Dias desordenados
        char[] diasDesordenados = new char[5];
        diasDesordenados[0]= 'L';
        diasDesordenados[1]= 'M';
        diasDesordenados[2]= 'C';
        diasDesordenados[3]= 'D'; //El domingo esta antes que el Viernes
        diasDesordenados[4]= 'V';

        int[] arregloDesordenados = Test.convertir(diasDesordenados);

        boolean resultadosDesordenados = Test.estaOrdenado(arregloDesordenados);


        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(diasDesordenados));
        System.out.println("Resultado desordenados: "+resultadosDesordenados);

        //Dias ordnados con huecos
        char[] diasOrdenados = new char[3];
        diasOrdenados[0]= 'M';//Martes
        diasOrdenados[1]= 'J';//Jueves
        diasOrdenados[2]= 'D';//Domingo

        int[] arregloOrdenados = Test.convertir(diasOrdenados);

        boolean resultadosOrdenados = Test.estaOrdenado(arregloOrdenados);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(diasOrdenados));
        System.out.println("Resultado ordenados: "+resultadosOrdenados);

    }

    public static int[] convertir(char[] arregloDias) {

        int tamanio = arregloDias.length;
        int[] convertido = new int[tamanio];

        char dia;
        int numeroDia;

        for(int indice=0; indice<tamanio;indice++) {
            dia= arregloDias[indice];
            numeroDia = Test.obtieneNumeroDia(dia);
            convertido[indice]= numeroDia;
        }

        return convertido;
    }


    public static int obtieneNumeroDia(char dia){
        int numeroDia = -1;

        switch(dia){
            case 'L': 
                numeroDia = 1;
                break;
            case 'M':
                numeroDia = 2;
                break;
            case 'C':
                numeroDia = 3;
                break;
            case 'J':
                numeroDia = 4;
                break;
            case 'V':
                numeroDia = 5;
                break;
            case 'S':
                numeroDia = 6;
                break;
            case 'D':
                numeroDia = 7;
                break;
        }

        return numeroDia;
    }


    public static boolean estaOrdenado(int[] dias){
        boolean resultado = true;


        if(dias.length!=1) {
            int tamanio = dias.length-2;
            for(int indice= 0; indice<=tamanio;indice++) {
                if(dias[indice]>dias[indice+1]) {
                    resultado = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }else {
            if(dias[0]==-1)
                resultado = false;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

[L, M, C, D, V]

Resultado desordenados: false

[M, J, D]

Resultado ordenados: true

Comment: Me equivoque y es que si puede haber saltos entre los dias de la semana ej: LMJ es correcto, pero LJM no porque no sigue el orden normal de una semana. no se si me explico. Con tu solucion casi esta, lo unico que faltaria lo anterior dicho. Gracias por responder

Comment: ¿Lo siguiente es válido? SDLM. Es decir empieza con Sábado o ¿Es obligatorio que empice con Lunes?